# conditional component render without using location.pathname React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm currently attempting to render components based off of what page the user is currently on. One of the components remains the same and which one is rendered with it will be determined on page location. I'm currently using `window.location.pathname` but this is not a desired behavior for us.

```
const Container = reduxForm({ form: 'login' })(LoginForm)
const currentLocation = window.location.pathname

const ExtraButtons = () => (
  <div className="row center-xs">
    <div className="col-xs-6 center-xs">
      <Link to={FORGOT_PASSWORD_ROUTE}>Forgot Password?</Link>
    </div>
  </div>
)

const Login = ({ loginStart, error, update, search, address, 
currentUser }) => (
  <div>
    <div className="row center-xs">
      <div className="col-xs-12">
        <img src={logo} className="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-xs">
        <Container onSubmit={loginStart} />
        {error && (
          <InputError
            visible={error && error !== null}
            errorMessage={error.message}
          />
        )}
        <ExtraButtons />
      </div>
      {currentLocation.includes('/login') ? (
        <div className="row center-xs start-xs col-xs">
          <LocSearch
            updateAddress={update}
            search={search}
            address={address}
          />
        </div>
      ) : currentLocation.includes('/home') ? (
        <div className="col-xs">
          <EmailSearch />
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { submitting, currentUser } = state.user
  const { address = '' } = state.locationSearch
  const error = state.error

  return {
    address,
    submitting,
    error,
    currentUser
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loginStart,
  resetError,
  update,
  search
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is, but why not use react-router?

Comment: You should use the history : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

Answer (score 0):

I think currentLocation is assigned the value when the script is loaded instead of when your component is rendered. that is the root cause. you should define currentLocation in your component.